# UUIDs for DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, uuid

Is it possible to get DynamoDB to automatically generate unique IDs when adding new items to a table?

I noticed the Java API mentions @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey so I'm assuming there's a way to get this working with PHP as well.

If so, does the application code generate these IDs or is it done on the DynamoDB side?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Good question - while conceptually possible, this seems not currently available as a DynamoDB API level feature, insofar neither [CreateTable](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_CreateTable.html) nor [PutItem](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_PutItem.html) refer to such a functionality.

The `@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey` notation you have noticed is a [Java annotation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation), i.e. syntactic sugar offered by the Java SDK indeed:

> An annotation, in the Java computer programming language, is a special
>   form of syntactic metadata that can be added to Java source code.

As such `@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey` is one of the *Amazon DynamoDB Annotations* offered as part of the *Object Persistence Model* within the Java SDK's high-level API (see [Using the Object Persistence Model with Amazon DynamoDB](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/JavaSDKHighLevel.html)):

> Marks a hash key or range key property as being auto-generated. The
>   Object Persistence Model will generate a random UUID when saving these
>   attributes. Only String properties can be marked as auto-generated
>   keys.

Comment: Thanks I'm not familiar with Java so your answer was really helpful. So @DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey is simply getting the Java API to generate a UUID, not Dynamo itself right? It would be really great if Dynamo had a UUID attribute type which would generate the IDs on their side and return them when adding new items.

Comment: @Adam: Indeed, `@DynamoDBAutoGeneratedKey` is simply a custom annotation provided by the Java SDK, which yields code being generated at compile time and in turn executed within the Java application to generate the UUID at runtime - this has nothing to do with DynamoDB as such. And I agree, a native DynamoDB UUID datatype would be quite convenient - let's hope the AWS team will expand the DynamoDB functionality over time, they are well known for responding to customer demand and innovate accordingly!

Answer (score 5):

While working with dynamodb in javascript with nodejs. I use the npm module uuid to genrate unique key.

Ex:

id=uuid.v1();

refer :[uuid npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)

Answer (score 2):

By using schema based **AWS dynamodb data mapper library in Node.js**, Hash key (id) will be generated automatically. Auto generated ids are based on uuid v4.

For more details, have a look on following aws package.

[Data Mapper with annotation](https://awslabs.github.io/dynamodb-data-mapper-js/packages/dynamodb-data-mapper-annotations/)

[Data Mapper package for Javascript](https://awslabs.github.io/dynamodb-data-mapper-js/)

Sample snipet

```
@table('my_table')
class MyDomainClass {
    @autoGeneratedHashKey()
    id: string;

    @rangeKey({defaultProvider: () => new Date()})
    createdAt: Date;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The client can create a (for all intents and purposes) unique ID either by picking a long random id (DynamoDB supports 128-bit integers, for example), or by picking an ID which contains the client's IP address, CPU number, and current time - or something along these lines.
The UUID standard even includes a standard way to do this (and you have libraries in various languages to create such UUIDs on the client side), but you don't really need to use a standard.
And interesting question is how do you plan to find these items if they have random keys. Or are you planning to use a secondary index?

Answer (score 1):

The 2022 answer is here:
https://dev.to/prabusah_53/aws-lambda-in-built-uuid-382f

External libraries are no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible and it's by design. You're probably using multi-table design so it makes sense in your scenario but it's not what AWS recommends and not the case for every ddb user.

Since AWS recommends single-table ddb design, it only makes sense that the user pass in the ids based on their use case.

For example, let's say you have a Blog table with `Post` and `Comment` entities in your table. You would want your ids for each to be `p#uuid` and `c#uuid`. And your table would look something like this:

| PK | SK | Entity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p#1 | p#1 | Post |
| p#1 | c#1 | Comment |
| p#1 | c#2 | Comment |
| p#2 | p#2 | Post |

How would ddb automatically know what your ids should be? When you add a second comment to the first post, how would it know to keep the primary key as `p#1` and only autogenerate the sort key for your comment to be `c#2`?

Almost all ddb sdks have some sort of utility function to generate a unique id. I'm not familiar with PHP too much but I'm sure there's a good way to generate a unique id in PHP as well.

Answer (score -5):

Here is another good method taken from mkyong

http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-current-timestamps-in-java/

I adjusted his method to get the milliseconds instead of the actual date

```
java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
System.out.println(new Timestamp(date.getTime()).getTime());
```

Answer (score -6):

The approach I'm taking is to use the current timestamp for the hash-key (or the range-key, if using a range-key too). Store the timestamp as an integer, representing the number of milliseconds since the start of the "UNIX epoch" (in the UTC timezone). Many date/time libraries can produce this number for you.

This has the advantage that if you want to have a "creation time" field in your table, your UUID already stores this information. Just call another method in your date/time library to convert the timestamp to a readable format.

(Be sure to handle the exception which will occur if a second item is created in the same table with the same millisecond timestamp; just fall back and retry the operation in that case, with a slightly later, current timestamp.)

For example:

> ```
> User table
> ```
>
> hash-key only: userID (timestamp of the creation of this user).
>
> ```
> WidgetAttributes table
> ```
>
> hash-key plus range-key.
> hash-key: userID (use the userID from the User table of the user to whom the widget belongs).
> range-key: attribID (use the timestamp of the creation of this widget-attribute).

Now you can run "query" operations on the WidgetAttributes table to get all widget-attributes for a certain user; by using "greater-than-zero" as the query-parameter for the range-key.

Comment: timestamp is not guaranteed to be unique, especially if multiple clients are running in parallel.

Comment: @shle2821 It'd be better to just generate a UUID for the id and store the timestamp in a separate field than this suggestion.